# How to create a non-LMT timezone object by pytz directly?

Tags: python, timezone, pytz

When I try to create a timezone object by pytz, I get a `LMT` timezone object like this:

```
>>> import pytz
>>> wrong_tz=pytz.timezone("Asia/Shanghai")
>>> wrong_tz
<DstTzInfo 'Asia/Shanghai' LMT+8:06:00 STD>
```

If I use this timezone object in datetime constructor, 6 min is missing (see the code in the end).

So I have to do this to get the right timezone object:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> dt = datetime(2020, 2, 2)
>>> right_tz = wrong_tz.localize(dt).tzinfo
>>> right_tz
<DstTzInfo 'Asia/Shanghai' CST+8:00:00 STD>
```

Here is my question: **How to get this `right_tz` directly?**

Using a datetime to do the converting is very ugly.

By the way, here is the different between `wrong_tz` and `right_tz`:

```
>>> datetime(2020, 2, 2, tzinfo=right_tz) - datetime(2020, 2, 2, tzinfo=wrong_tz)
datetime.timedelta(seconds=360)
```

Comment: btw. your last line of code is actually wrong; you can find more info on how (and how not) to use pytz's time zones [here](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2018/03/pytz-fastest-footgun.html).

Comment: @MrFuppes Thank you. That blog helps me to understand why pytz would do this.

Comment: In short, the LMT is just the first entry from the database. If you use pytz, you *have* to adjust it to a specific time by using `localize` or `astimezone`. As an alternative, with [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) or zoneinfo (Python 3.9), you'd have semantics that better fit into how you'd normally use Python's datetime.